# Refactoring - Should I leave redundant if case

Tags: c#, refactoring

I was fixing a bug on this very long and verbose method in c#, and kept finding these redundant `if`s all over the place.

es

```
//var objParam = new SqlParameter(); var cmd = new SqlCommand(); var myVar = new Foo();
objParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeParam", SqlType.NVarchar, 40);
if(myVar.SomeParam.Length > 4)
    objParam.Value = myVar.SomeParam.Substring(0, 40);
else
    objParam.Value = myVar.SomeParam;
```

these `if`s are repeated a million times everywhere, and are always `SqlType.NVarChar`.

My question is, should I leave those? I suppose it doesn't make the code slower or anything, but the methods are longer and it doesn't help readability.

I think they should all be replaced with

```
objParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeParam", SqlType.NVarchar, n);
objParam.Value = myVar.SomeParam.Substring(0, n);
```

with `n` the number of the characters obviously.

NOTE: I know that this VB6-esque way of adding parameters is very old but I'm trying for my boss not to notice all the small refactorings I do on these old programs ;)

Comment: You could put the case in a method...

Comment: I advise you to not change code of someone else if it is working. If the product is yours ok, if it is not you can have only problems from that.
1) You can inject bug -> in this case the chance is low.
2) The creator programmer can see it and not be pleased about it. Everybody have a way of working. I don't defend this code, it is stupid, but there are guys which can be offend by this. As performance it is not a big deal, as readability is really bad.

Comment: `>the creator of the program can see it and not be pleased about it` I'm working, not pleasing other programmers. My point is to leave after me code that every programmer will read simply, methods that can be read in a single screen (screen? I mean without scrolling). The ultimate goal is to work better and more efficiently.

Comment: Is the "4" supposed to be "40"?

Answer (score 1):

Create this method:

```
private static string getSomeParam(var myVar) => 
    myVar.SomeParam.Length > 40 ? myVar.SomeParam.SubString(0, 40) 
                                : myVar.SomeParam;
```

And then use it like so:

```
//var objParam = new SqlParameter(); var cmd = new SqlCommand(); var myVar = new Foo();
objParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeParam", SqlType.NVarchar, 40);
objParam.Value = getSomeParam(myVar);
```

This will add readablity, as well as making it easy to editing this method in the future. So if you decide to make the `40` into a constant `maxLength` or something of that one place.

If you want to change the value of `myVar` in `getSomeParam()`:

```
private static string getSomeParam(var myVar, var out objParam) =>
    objParam.Value = myVar.SomeParam.Length > 40 ? myVar.SomeParam.SubString(0, 40) 
                                                 : myVar.SomeParam;
```

And call it like this:

```
objParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SomeParam", SqlType.NVarchar, 40);
getSomeParam(myVar, out objParam);
```

Comment: what if I reassign the myVar in the method with the `.Substring` if the condition is meeted?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding 40, add another parameter to the method for maxlength

Comment: With "redundant `if`s all over the place" you would end up with lots of identically-looking `getSomeParam` methods all over the place. This would be the same code duplication, only in a different place.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, but its a much smaller problem, one that supports further procedural abstraction, increases readability, and easier to edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you have identically-looking `if`s that perform a meaningful operation, making a helper method is a good idea. Not only would it make your code shorter and easier to read, but also eliminate potentially harmful copying, perfectly illustrated by the typo in your question:

```
if(myVar.SomeParam.Length > 4) // <<= This const should be 40, not 4
    objParam.Value = myVar.SomeParam.Substring(0, 40);
else
    objParam.Value = myVar.SomeParam;
```

Make a helper that looks like this:

```
private static SqlParameter AddNvarchar(SqlCommand cmd, string name, int size, string val) {
    var res = cmd.Parameters.Add(name, SqlType.NVarchar, size);
    if(val.Length > size)
        res.Value = val.Substring(0, 40);
    else
        res.Value = val;
    return res;
}
```

Now you can replace multi-line assignments with this:

```
var objParam = AddNvarchar(cmd, "@SomeParam", 40, myVar.SomeParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the real issue - why you call this "redundant" code - is that if you were to take the substring of a string whose length is shorter than 40, you would simply get the original string back.  So writing logic to only take the substring if it's longer than 40 is adding logic, complexity, and risk to your code base unnecessarily.

Unfortunately, that's not the way the C# substring method works - if you give it too short a string, it will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.  So the checks are not redundant.  A different way to write this would be:

```
objParam.Value = myVar.SomeParam.Substring(0, Math.Max(40, SomeParam.Length));
```